# Please consider reopening or otherwise give suggestions for improvement: Are the chessmaster lectures (insert antonym of outdated)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open

[Are the chessmaster lectures (insert antonym of outdated)?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/are-the-chessmaster-lectures-insert-antonym-of-outdated)

There was only 1 question really mainly. 1 was a follow up of another and 1 was a side question. In any case I now literally have only 1 question mark in the body of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reopened. Thus the question is completed and accounted for.